# Component automagically wrapped with additional v-container when loaded with router-view

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I'm writing here, because I cannot find the response, or better, I found myself unable to formulate proper question to find it.
My question is:

Given the App.vue structure: (simplified)

```
<v-main>
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
     <router-view />
  </v-container>
</v-main>
```

and the Component.vue structure:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col>
    Component Content
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Why is the rendered component wrapped with the plain `<v-container>`?:

```
<main class="v-main" style="padding: 64px 0px 0px;">
    <div class="v-main__wrap">
       <div class="container container--fluid fill-height"> // App.vue
          <div class="container">  // ????
             <div class="row"> // component code
                <div class="col">
```

Is it some secret `vue-router` or `vuetify` template?
Could anyone explain why this happens and if there is a way to avoid this?

Edit: versions:

```
   Dependencies:
                req:    inst:
   core-js      ^3.8.3  3.21.1  
   vue          ^2.6.14 2.6.14  
   vue-router   ^3.5.1  3.5.3   
   vuetify      ^2.6.0  2.6.4   
   vuex         ^3.6.2  3.6.2   

Dev dependencies:
                        req:        inst:
@babel/core             ^7.12.16    7.17.7
@babel/eslint-parser    ^7.12.16    7.17.0  
@vue/cli-plugin-babel   ~5.0.0      5.0.3   
@vue/cli-plugin-eslint  ~5.0.0      5.0.3   
@vue/cli-plugin-router  ~5.0.0      5.0.3   
@vue/cli-plugin-vuex    ~5.0.0      5.0.3   
@vue/cli-service        ~5.0.0      5.0.3   
eslint                  ^7.32.0     7.32.0  
eslint-plugin-vue       ^8.0.3      8.5.0   
sass                    ~1.32.0     1.32.13 
sass-loader             ^10.0.0     10.2.1  
vue-cli-plugin-vuetify  ^2.4.7      2.4.7   
vue-template-compiler   ^2.6.14     2.6.14  
vuetify-loader          ^1.7.0      1.7.3
```

Comment: What version of vuetify are you using? Can't reproduce the issue. Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71690542-bug-v-container-wrapper-chtpcd?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I'm using 2.6.4, thanks for the sandbox, it's true it's not happening there. Also the vuetify plugin content is slightly different from the one in my project (installed with vue ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad, I didn't realize that it was because the parent component of this particular subview `<v-container>` wasn't marked as fluid.
All fixed now. Since the parent was only a template with a container and a router-view without any logic, I'd completely forgotten about it.